# Windows File Permissions - Comparing to chmod

Tags: windows, permissions, chmod

I am using an SAP specific tool (like Winzip) called SAPCAR to compress and decompress files into archives.

I have a file from SAP called **KA71007.SAR**

When I view the contents of this archive it displays:

SAPCAR -tvf /KA71007.SAR
-rw-------         324    31 Oct 2008 11:14 EPS/in/CSR0120031469_0033811.ATT
-rw-------    15515097    31 Oct 2008 11:10 EPS/in/CSR0120031469_0033811.PAT

I would like the files to have these permissions:

-rw-rw-rw-         324    31 Oct 2008 11:14 EPS/in/CSR0120031469_0033811.ATT
-rw-rw-rw-    15515097    31 Oct 2008 11:10 EPS/in/CSR0120031469_0033811.PAT

If I was using a UNIX server I could extract the 2 files from the archive and run 'chmod 666 *'. However I am running on Windows, so I have:

- Selected both files
- Chosen to not inherit permissions from the parent folder
- Given full control to all user groups listed (Administrators, Users, Owner) and I have also added group 'Everyone'

Then I ran this:

sapcar -cvf KA71007.SAR *

to repackage both files into the archive KA71007.SAR

Then I ran: SAPCAR -tvf /KA71007.SAR

But the result is still:

-rw-------         324    31 Oct 2008 11:14 EPS/in/CSR0120031469_0033811.ATT
-rw-------    15515097    31 Oct 2008 11:10 EPS/in/CSR0120031469_0033811.PAT

Is it possible to change the values of the files to rw rw rw (666) in Windows, or will Windows simply not show the changes in this manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By the Power of Google!**

http://www.easymarketplace.de/SAPCAR.php

SAPCAR needs the -acl option to preserve Windows file permissions.

Comment: +1 - didn't spot the -acl option when I checked, deleted my answer

Comment: That website lists the parameter -acl but it looks like that does not exist in recent versions of the sapcar program (it is now listed when I look at the application help.

However -backup (run in backup mode: include ACL data. supported by UNICODE SAPCar on Windows platforms only) is listed and would seem to do the same thing.

The only problem is that this is not working, but I have asked about it here https://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1439638. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "By the Power of Google!" nice.